# Detect System Info including Processor, RAM, Graphics Memory, and Harddisk

Tags: adobe, air

i would like to know if following information is available in a desktop based AIR applicatiopn
Processor, RAM, Graphics Memory, and Harddisk.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know of these these properties:

```
flash.system.System.privateMemory // Ram in use by application
flash.system.System.totalMemory // Ram total avail
```

I'm pretty sure hard disk and GPU info is not available. Perhaps these are also of use to you:

```
flash.system.Capabilities.cpuArchitecture // "PowerPC", "x86", "SPARC", and "ARM"
flash.system.Capabilities.supports32BitProcesses //Boole
flash.system.Capabilities.supports64BitProcesses //Boole
```